# Cropping an image in android

Tags: java, android, camera, tablet

I am using the [takePicture function in the Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29) to continuously take and store pictures on a tablet. I need to know how I can crop the data that is stored upon calling takePicture. Or, if that is not possible, then I need to know how I can read in an image and then use something else to crop it. So far the only solutions I've found to this problem require opening another app to crop. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code to crop the image:

> ```
> final String Path = "sdcard/test.jpg";
>  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Path);
>  ivSign.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, true));
>  Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
>  // indicate image type and Uri
>  cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Path)), "image/*");
>  // set crop properties
>  cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
>  // indicate aspect of desired crop
>  cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
>  cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
>  // indicate output X and Y
>  cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
>  cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
>  // retrieve data on return
>  cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
>  // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
>  startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 1);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> From the Below Code you will get correct Idea. sometimes you will get
>   Problems if the device is like **Samsung Galaxy S3 and you wants to crop image after capturing as they**
>    **are returning null intent after capturing image.**

After spending hours on this issue i finally make it work by Below Way if some one is having this problem in future.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

    private String selectedImagePath = "";
    boolean GallaryPhotoSelected = false;

    public static String Finalmedia = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final String[] items = new String[] { "Take from camera",
                "Select from gallery" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
                                                                    // camera
                if (item == 0) {
                    String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

                    if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        // intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        // mImageCaptureUri);
                        // if (hasImageCaptureBug()) {

                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                .getName()
                                + File.separatorChar
                                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                        File file = new File(path);
                        // mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(
                        // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        // "tmp_avatar_"
                        // + String.valueOf(System
                        // .currentTimeMillis())
                        // + ".jpg"));
                        Log.i("TAG", "Final  path" + path);
                        try {
                            if (file.exists() == false) {
                                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                                file.createNewFile();
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("TAG", "Could not create file.", e);
                        }
                        mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        intent.putExtra(
                                android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                mImageCaptureUri);
                        // } else {
                        // intent.putExtra(
                        // android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        // android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        // }

                        try {
                            // intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setMessage(
                                        "External Storeage (SD Card) is required.\n\nCurrent state: "
                                                + storageState)
                                .setCancelable(true).create().show();
                    }

                } else { // pick from file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_crop);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean hasImageCaptureBug() {

        // list of known devices that have the bug
        ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();
        devices.add("android-devphone1/dream_devphone/dream");
        devices.add("generic/sdk/generic");
        devices.add("vodafone/vfpioneer/sapphire");
        devices.add("tmobile/kila/dream");
        devices.add("verizon/voles/sholes");
        devices.add("google_ion/google_ion/sapphire");

        return devices.contains(android.os.Build.BRAND + "/"
                + android.os.Build.PRODUCT + "/" + android.os.Build.DEVICE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            Log.i("TAG", "Inside PICK_FROM_CAMERA");
            // mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            // Bitmap bm1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            // mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm1);
            // Bundle extras1 = data.getExtras();
            // Bitmap bm1 = (Bitmap) extras1.get("data");
            // mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm1);

            /*
             * try { if (hasImageCaptureBug()) { Log.i("TAG", "Inside Bug");
             * selectedImagePath = String.valueOf(System .currentTimeMillis()) +
             * ".jpg"; File fi = new File(
             * Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), selectedImagePath);
             * try { mImageCaptureUri = Uri
             * .parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
             * .insertImage(getContentResolver(), fi.getAbsolutePath(), null,
             * null)); if (!fi.delete()) { Log.i("logMarker",
             * "Failed to delete " + fi); } } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             * e.printStackTrace(); } } else { mImageCaptureUri =
             * data.getData(); } } catch (Exception e) { Log.i("TAG",
             * "Inside Bug"); selectedImagePath =
             * String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"; File fi =
             * new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
             * selectedImagePath); try { mImageCaptureUri = Uri
             * .parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
             * .insertImage(getContentResolver(), fi.getAbsolutePath(), null,
             * null)); if (!fi.delete()) { Log.i("logMarker",
             * "Failed to delete " + fi); } } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
             * e1.printStackTrace(); } }
             */

            String path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
            Log.i("TAG",
                    "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!After capture path "
                            + path);

            doCrop();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            Log.i("TAG",
                    "After Crop mImageCaptureUri " + mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
            GallaryPhotoSelected = true;
            doCrop();

            break;

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            selectedImagePath = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();

            Log.i("TAG", "After Crop selectedImagePath " + selectedImagePath);

            if (GallaryPhotoSelected) {
                selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri);
                Log.i("TAG", "Absolute Path " + selectedImagePath);
                GallaryPhotoSelected = true;
            }

            Finalmedia = selectedImagePath;

            if (extras != null) {
                // Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                Log.i("TAG", "Inside Extra " + selectedImagePath);
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                selectedImagePath = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg";

                Log.i("TAG", "new selectedImagePath before file "
                        + selectedImagePath);

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        selectedImagePath);

                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, fos);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Sorry, Camera Crashed-Please Report as Crash A.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                selectedImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/" + selectedImagePath;
                Log.i("TAG", "After File Created  " + selectedImagePath);

                Bitmap bm = decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }

            /*
             * File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
             * 
             * if (f.exists()) f.delete();
             */

            break;

        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        int orientation;
        try {
            if (path == null) {
                return null;
            }
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            // while (true) {
            // if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
            // || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            // break;
            // width_tmp /= 2;
            // height_tmp /= 2;
            // scale++;
            // }
            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
            Bitmap bitmap = bm;

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);

            orientation = exif
                    .getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

            Log.e("ExifInteface .........", "rotation =" + orientation);

            // exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90, 90);

            Log.e("orientation", "" + orientation);
            Matrix m = new Matrix();

            if ((orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)) {
                m.postRotate(180);
                // m.postScale((float) bm.getWidth(), (float) bm.getHeight());
                // if(m.preRotate(90)){
                Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                        bm.getHeight(), m, true);
                return bitmap;
            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                m.postRotate(90);
                Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                        bm.getHeight(), m, true);
                return bitmap;
            } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                m.postRotate(270);
                Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                        bm.getHeight(), m, true);
                return bitmap;
            }
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                intent, 0);

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        } else {

            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
            intent.setClassName("com.android.camera",
                    "com.android.camera.CropImage");
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 100);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                        res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                            res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                            res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent
                            .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                    res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                    res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                        CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                            }
                        });

                builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null,
                                    null);
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```